# the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am new to Web Sevice, I am getting the following error when I tried to run my page (**Local**) in Chrome Console

**ERROR**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) `http://localhost:12015/myWebService.asmx?op=GetCategories`

---

Here is the related code:

*jQuery*

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:12015/myWebService.asmx?op=GetCategories",
     type: "POST",
     ------------
     ------------
    success: function (data) {                    
         var categories = data.d;
         $.each(categories, function (index, category) {
             category.CategoryId).text(category.CategoryName);
         });
    },
    error: function (e) {  //always executing 'error' only
         alert("hello");
    }
```

*web service URL*

> `http://localhost:12015/myWebService.asmx`

---

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public List<Categories>  GetCategories()
 {
      //code
 }
```

*Page URL*

> `http://localhost:11761/Default.aspx`

EDIT:  The error gone when I just included `dataType: 'jsonp'` But now there is another error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   `:12015/myWebService.asmx?op=GetCategories&callback=jQuery183010907560377381742_1356599550427&{}&_=1356599550438:3`

When I clicked the link(which was mentioned in the error), it is displaying the page. Then what could be the problem ? I dont know what the error means (and also which part of code to show). Please help.

**Related**

[**Link1**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14053484/1577396) (explanation)
[**Link2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14122895/1577396) (solved)

Comment: http://localhost:12015/myWebService.asmx <-- is this accessible, im guessing it's a web server issue, IIS configuration maybe

Comment: @mdcuesta yes, sorry I forgot to mention everything is local(I mean on my PC itself)

Comment: Is your `dataType='jsonp'`?

Comment: It's look like your are doing a GET not a POST

Comment: you can have a look at this:http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: @ronen..  I am doing POST as I mentioned in my code.

Comment: @ronen see in ajax he used `'post'`

Comment: @jai yes my dataType is 'jsonp' (BTW, no need to mention, its default)

Comment: can you paste your `success: function` need to see how you are accessing the response

Comment: So it is not supposed to be like this: `http://localhost:12015/myWebService.asmx/GetCategories`

Comment: @ronen I tried that, it was showing `error 500` so I changed to this... (I copied the url of `GetCategories` in my ajax call)

Comment: The big question: does your webservice accept `POST` requests? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618900/enable-asp-net-asmx-web-service-for-http-post-get-requests

Comment: @SalmanA not sure about that.. any link to start with might help me?

Comment: Do you have this attribute over your service class: `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` ?

Comment: check this one:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/31d3f1aa-28b6-4bd7-b031-73b7e7588e6d/

Comment: No, you have to add this attribute over your service class declaration like this: `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] public class myWebService`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a simple line on my friend's suggestion above the jquery ajax call

```
 jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Now it is working fine :)

ONLY IN **IE** BROWSER

I would be happy to know if it can be solved using different way as it is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7852225/1577396).

Anyhow I asked this question again after many efforts and I got different error which was solved in this post [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14053484/1577396)

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpPost = true)]
 public List<Categories>  GetCategories()
 {
      //code
 }
```

or edit `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
              <add name="HttpSoap"/> 
              <add name="HttpPost"/> --> 
              <add name="HttpGet"/>
              <add name="Documentation"/>
              <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Refer http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2006/12/22/How-to-enable-an-ASP.NET-WebService-to-listen-to-HTTP.aspx

Comment: I need to use only `json` cant change it.. (restricted)

Comment: you are using `type: "POST",` in jquery ajax call, so the webservice should allow `post` request you can do it by editing `web.config` file too. please see http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2006/12/22/How-to-enable-an-ASP.NET-WebService-to-listen-to-HTTP.aspx

Comment: web.config file of webservice

Answer (score 3):

make your content type as "application/json; charset=utf-8", as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "RSSReader.asmx/GetRSSReader",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
  // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
  $('#RSSContent').removeClass('loading');

  // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
  $('#RSSContent').html(msg.d);
 }
});
});
```

also refer [link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, in my case was working in debug mode but when I published the solution the delete method was not working but I already had the content type, I just needed to add the charset=utf-8

Answer (score 3):

in my case it was failing becasue of there was not POST method in servet, but I had GET method.

so I jsut changed the type:"GET", so it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Add Allow Access All Origin In The Server Side

Comment: You should have mentioned this as a comment than an answer.