# WCF jQuery post data doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, rest, cross-domain

I have some trouble with an WCF Service: This Service should communicate with an AJAX Client, which is running  on a other Server. So, I have a crossDomain problem. I search and work 2 days but I don't find some solution, that is quite easy to understand.

When I use Fiddler, they could communicate with the server but only when set the content-length attribute to zero.

GET method are also working but PUTs never.

Here is some code for the orientation:

## Server Methods:

### Model:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    private string id;
    [DataMember]
    private string name;

    public Person(string id, string name)
    {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

  }
```

### Serverinterface & Implementation:

```
   [ServiceContract]
   interface IPersonService
   {
       ...

       [OperationContract]
       Person InsertPerson(Person person);
   }

 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
 public class PersonService : IPersonService
 {

     [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/POST/PersonPost", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Person InsertPerson(Person per)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("InsertPerson");
        if (per == null)
        {
            return new Person("2", "null");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("POST:[PersonId = {0} PersonName = {1}]", per.Id, per.Name);
         return new Person("1", "InsertPerson");
    }
```

## and finally the Client

```
var person = '{"per":{';
                person = person + '"id":"' + '"abc123"' + '",'
                person = person + '"name":"' + '"john"' + '"'
                person = person + '}}';

                alert(person);
                $.support.cors = true;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: person,
                    processData: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: "http://localhost:59291/Person/POST/PersonPost",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Post erfolgreich: ");

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Fehler Post: Status " + xhr.status + " AntwortText " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Can someone tell me what can I do, to bring this to work:
In short, currently I don't have a connection to the Server when I use my jQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use an object:

```
var myObject ={};
myObject.Id = '';
myObject.Name ='';
```

and use `JSON.stringify(myObject);`

May want to remove this from your ajax call : `dataType: "jsonp",` also you may want to check the problem from this question [Cross domain ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477527/cross-domain-ajax-request).

```
    var person = {};
person.id ="abc123";
person.name ="aaaa";
var per = {};
per.per = person;

                $.support.cors = true;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(per),
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    processData: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: "http://localhost:59291/Person/POST/PersonPost",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Post erfolgreich: ");

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Fehler Post: Status " + xhr.status + " AntwortText " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Fehler Post: Status 200 AntwortText undefined

Comment: I take .NET 4.5, do you know how I could enable CORS in the Visual Studion debugging

Comment: you are are the men, now I have access to my method in the server. But how can I have access to my Person object, which the client sent by the data

Comment: one minute Floradu88, can you perhaps say how could I have access to the objects/data in the Servermethod

Comment: there is still the jsonp for the datatype but is that correct?
and I think the access to the server still work in the IE not in chrome. but first i check your tip

Comment: it doesn't work: it is very strange in the IE the method will started, but there is the per object NULL, and via Chrome, there can I don't start the method

Comment: it is working like before, in the server method I don't have access to the data: did you know why the IE is accepting the jQuery Script and Chrome not

Comment: do you think my insertPerson method is correct, or must I there make some changes

Comment: I don't think so, where can I check this

Comment: f12 on chrome and check console tab. provide a prinscreen in the question if there is something with red.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:59291/Person/POST/PersonPost. Origin http://ogwnanqvtest is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: what, I don't understand you; you are very friendly;)

Comment: do you have still some tips for me

Comment: put this back: dataType: "jsonp", if this does not work then you will need to screen share for more tips.

Comment: check my previous comment out

Comment: then I get this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) http://localhost:59291/Person/POST/PersonPost?callback=jQuery19103718682825…&{%22per%22:{%22id%22:%22abc123%22,%22name%22:%22aaaa%22}}&_=1363954689947

Comment: and the IE doesn't activate the method in the server

Comment: check this question out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051432/the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-405-method-not-allowed

Comment: the suggestion they made is to include the jQuery client into the main project but this is not what i can do