# Error when calling webservice from typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

I have the following typescript implementation:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
interface INotificationService {
    serviceUrl: string;
    getNotifications(onNotificationReceived: (notifications: string) => any): void;
}
module GRCcontrol.Messaging {
    export class Notifier implements INotificationService {
        private serviceUrl: string;
        constructor(serviceUrl: string) {
            this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
        }
        getNotifications(onNotificationReceived: (notifications: string) => any) {
            var that = this;
            $.getJSON(that.serviceUrl, {}, function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            });
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var notifier = new GRCcontrol.Messaging.Notifier("http://clwebsvr01/wp7test/api/user/getemail/P6dNT1EFOKYPtHxdPWgng2lKyMg=");
    notifier.getNotifications(function (notifications) {
        alert(notifications);
    });
});
```

The output in Javascript is this:

```
var GRCcontrol;
(function (GRCcontrol) {
    (function (Messaging) {
        var Notifier = (function () {
            function Notifier(serviceUrl) {
                this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
            }
            Notifier.prototype.getNotifications = function (onNotificationReceived) {
                var that = this;
                $.getJSON(that.serviceUrl, {
                }, function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }).fail(function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                });
            };
            return Notifier;
        })();
        Messaging.Notifier = Notifier;        
    })(GRCcontrol.Messaging || (GRCcontrol.Messaging = {}));
    var Messaging = GRCcontrol.Messaging;
})(GRCcontrol || (GRCcontrol = {}));
$(document).ready(function () {
    var notifier = new GRCcontrol.Messaging.Notifier("http://clwebsvr01/wp7test/api/user/getemail/P6dNT1EFOKYPtHxdPWgng2lKyMg=");
    notifier.getNotifications(function (notifications) {
        alert(notifications);
    });
});
```

The problem is that it keeps getting into the fail method and returns status = 0 and statusText = error.
I used Fiddler to see if the call is done, and fiddler receives the response without problems.

How can i get this thing to work properly?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a TypeScript issue. You could try adding a JavaScript tag, and also posting the JS output from the TS compiler, as that might help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JcFx i have updated my question with extra info.

Comment: I think that makes it easier. I can't see anything wrong with the JS myself, but there are others on here with more JQuery knowledge who may be able to. The only thing I would do is `console.log` `that.serviceUrl` in `getNotifications`, to make sure it is correct, and also log the entire server response, or put a debugger stop there to see what the issue might be - but you may well have done all this previously.

Comment: @JcFx I already tried the things you suggested, but still no luck. I really hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Rob - I hope so, too. All I can say is it doesn't look like a scripting issue. More likely the wrong method (GET/POST) or something else that differs between the JQuery AJAX call and the test you're doing in fiddler, or a cross domain issue with the cors support not working so the browser is blocking the response, but these are just hunches. If it's really holding you up, you might try another browser, or a JSONP request to see if that works.

Comment: Rob, can you confirm that what you see in Fiddler is the request, not just the preceding `OPTIONS` call that CORS uses to check the server is happy to make the actual request?

Comment: @SteveFenton i can confirm this. The results are displayed in Fiddler like they should. I'm pretty sure the problem should be somewhere else, but i don't know where... JcFX i will try this tomorrow when i'm back at the office, thanks!

Comment: @JcFx The problem was indeed the cross-domain call. Cors support is not working from TypeScript. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: Rob - TypeScript compiles and runs just as JavaScript, so it's not a case of the `cors` call not being supported in TS - it surely would not have worked even if you have written the JS by hand. Glad it's fixed, though.

Comment: @JcFx i will give that a try and see if your right, just to be sure :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not appear to have been a TypeScript issue at all, but rather a problem with the JavaScript/JQuery attempt to make a `cors` enabled ajax call.

For good reason, `cors` doesn't allow blanket access to all cross-domain resources. See this SO question and answers for more details: [Is it safe to use $.support.cors = true; in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852225/is-it-safe-to-use-support-cors-true-in-jquery)