# Sending json via form vs. jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms, post

I have a simple form in which I can successfully create a new project using Asana's API

```
<form action="https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects" id="newProject" method="post" name="myform">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
    <input id="workspace" name="workspace" type="text" value="498346170860">
    <input id="new" type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

This works fine. A project is created and a I get json output returned in the browser window.

But when I try to use .post .ajax methods, I get ""Request data must be a JSON object, not null" returned. For example (coffeescript):

```
$("form").submit ->
    $.post $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), ((jsonData) ->
        console.log jsonData
    ), "json"
```

Comment: Thats cross domain so youd need to use `jsonp` or have some kind of local proxy on the server side that can make requests to external domains.

Comment: Or you can do ajax request with all parameters to your server and do API request via your server

Comment: Assume I have browser security disabled, etc. It still wouldn't work? Is there a way to submit the html form above but catch the response from the server before it opens a new tab/page?

Comment: Also, the Asana api doesn't support jsonp. :/

Answer (score 0):

Put `jQuery.support.cors = true;` somewhere above your cross domain ajax request.  [Read more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7852225/945875).

Also, you may want to specify the contentType `"application/json"`