# Set height and width of IFRAME in cross domain environment?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I set height and width of IFRAME in cross domain environment?

How can I access `contentDocument` of IFRAME in cross domain environment?

Answer (score 0):

We can use **IFRAME in cross domain environment**. But we have to use an **ajax call** and **IFRAME configurations**. Below is the code. It worked for me. I have searched many area. Atlast I got this working code.

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="doc-frame" src="javascript:(function () {document.open();document.domain='localhost';document.close();})();" style="width:100%;height:100%;" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In IFRAME we have to set the domain as same domain of the requesting window document. Else it will not work. Here I have set localhost.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.support.cors = true;
            var frameSize = 0;
            $("#doc-frame").css({ 'height': frameSize, 'width': frameSize, 'zoom': '100%' });
            $.ajax({
                url: fileNamePath,// URL of the request page
                context: document.body,
                success: function (response) {
                    target = $("#doc-frame")[0].contentDocument;
                    target.open();
                    target.write(response);
                    target.close();
                    var frameMargin = 10;
                    $("#doc-frame").css("height", parseFloat($('#doc-frame').contents().height() + frameMargin) + "px");
                    $('#doc-frame').css("width", parseFloat($("#doc-frame").contents().width() + frameMargin) + "px");
                }
            });
```

It will work. Please use this code and please let me know the comments, drawbacks and limitations. I don't think this can fulfill all our **cross domain IFRAME** needs. But in some situations, we can use it.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you overriding jQuery's CORS support detection? What good will it do to make jQuery try to use CORS in a browser that doesn't support it?

Comment: Overriding jQuery's CORS support detection is not "using CORS".

Comment: It did nothing for you (other then perhaps making it screw up worse in older browsers that don't support CORS).

Comment: For ajax request in cross domain environment, how it can get response??? for that purpose i used it...

Comment: `$.support.cors` is set by jQuery, when you load jQuery, after it tests to see if the browser supports CORS. It is intended to be used internally by jQuery. It is not intended to be touched by developers. You use CORS without touching the `$.support.cors` variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852225/is-it-safe-to-use-support-cors-true-in-jquery

Comment: — Yes, overriding jQuery's CORS detection doesn't introduce a *security* vulnerability. That doesn't mean it makes any sense to do it though.

Comment: did not work for me (chrome), was loading something in cache